# ionice process group?

Tags: linux, posix, nice, ionice

Is there an easy way to change the I/O priority of a whole group of processes the way `renice -g` does?  It seems like only changing the I/O priority of a single process is supported by `ionice`.  If this can't be done, can someone please point me to the the relevant API calls (I'm not at all familiar with the POSIX api) so that I can write a quick command line utility to implement this functionality myself?

Answer (score 3):

You can make a script called gionice, like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
ps -s $1 -o pid | xargs ionice -c 2 -n 0 -p
```

Then, you can call it like that, for process group id 3266, for example:

```
./gionice 3266
```

"ps -s PID -o pid" prints line-by-line identifiers of processes whose group leader is PID.
Then, for every line, xargs appends that line after "ionice -c 2 -n 0 -p " and calls the resulting command.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at cgroups and the blkio module?

http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cgroups.txt

You can use it to limit IO with a lot more control then ionice alone. You can also use the cgrulesengd daemon to automatically add new processes to your existing group infrastructure.